# Custom helper for jQuery UI Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a jQuery UI draggable, and I've tried to create a custom helper which would contain some but not all information of the original element.

Here's my draggable elements;

```
<ul>
  <li><div>Name</div> <span>12-12-2011</span></li>
  <li><div>Another name</div> <span>12-12-2011</span></li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery;

```
$("ul li").draggable(function(){
  helper: function(){
    return $("<div></div>");
  }
});
```

The idea would be that while dragging, the user would have a helper that contains only the name, but not the time element.

My actual code is slightly more complex than this even, so what I'm really looking for is any selector that would allow me to select the original element, or a copy of it, and then do all kinds of jQuery magic on it (filtering elements, adding new elements, classes, etc.)

However, for my life I can't find this, the documentation of draggable sucks and nobody at #jquery would help me. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is you requirement for the element to drop too? My first attempt at an answer provide the same results as the others in that is custom dragged, but would not allow drop. So I found a work around for dropping too. Do you not need to actually move the original element?

Comment: I don't need to move the original element, what I'm looking for is a sort of a customized clone.

Comment: Hey, I would know how do you reposition your custom clone after that ? For example, I have an element, 500x200 and I need it to be 175x50 while dragging it, So I use helper with a function returning a "sort of a customized clone" in 175x50 but when I start Dragging, my cloned element, begins from the left top corner of the full element no matter where the cursor is... Any solution?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First your way of calling `draggable` is faulty. The expected parameter is an object literal, not a function.

`this` is the currently dragged element in the `helper` function.

Having the following html

```
<ul>
  <li><div class="name">Name</div> <span>12-12-2011</span></li>
  <li><div class="name">Another name</div> <span>12-12-2011</span></li>
</ul>
```

You can do this:

```
$('ul li').draggable({
    helper: function() {
        //debugger;
        return $("<div></div>").append($(this).find('.name').clone());
    }
});
```

Note: I have added class to the `<div>` representing the name for the sake of selecting it but you can find any other way to do so.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/QsjqP/) for you to check.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! However, I'd like to know more about the bizarre way this seems to work. For example, saving $(this).find('.name') into a variable like you would anywhere else in jQuery, in order to call additional functions on it doesn't seem to work here. Why's that?

Comment: I am not sure to understand. Within the helper function you mean ? Could you fork my fiddle and modify the javascript to illustrate ?

Answer (score 9):

OK, with a quick test the following will work....

```
$("ul li").draggable({
    helper: function() {
        return $("<div>hello</div>");
    } });
```

notice you do not pass a function as a draggable parameter. Also, I have added "hello" to the example so the helper DIV actually contains something.

**EDIT**: This seems to prevent the element being dropped, hmmm...

**A FIX**: Not pretty, but this works, maybe it can give some ideas for improvement...

```
var remember;
$("ul li").draggable({
    helper: 'original',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        remember = $(this).html();
        $(this).html("<div>hello</div>");
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).html(remember);
    }
});
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp8DC/)

If you don't like the idea of the "remember" variable it seems to be ok to add a custom option to the draggable object that can hold the original html...

```
$("ul li").draggable({
    helper: 'original',
    start: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).draggable("option", "olddata", $(this).html());
        $(this).html("<div>hello</div>");
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).html($(this).draggable("option", "olddata"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SWbse/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("ul li").draggable({
         helper: 'clone',
         start: function(event, ui){
            ui.helper.children('span').remove();
         }    
     });
   });
```