# jquery ui draggable convert tr into div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a large table with many rows, each with a drag handler.

Which event would I use so that I can modify the HTML and change the `<tr>` into `<div>`?

Comment: What's your plan with the td data?

Comment: As in, how can you change a cloned element to a div? Or are you removing the row from the table? Show some code.

Comment: `How could I event the draggable event ` what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to read that over

Comment: The plan to to convert cell 1 into h2, cell 2 into p, etc. All contained within a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a custom helper.  See this SO question: [Custom helper for jQuery UI Draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501887/custom-helper-for-jquery-ui-)

Basically, you want to wrap your content in a `div` instead of the `tr`.  A consequence of this will be that you now have `td`'s as children of the `div` which isn't going to fly!  So you can do one of two things:

1. You can strip out just the content from the row or even specific fields (the SO question I posted is doing just that -- pulling only certain elements for the drag)
2. You could, instead of stipping the `tr` **wrap** the tr in a table element, making the drag event a valid stand-alone DOM fragment, i.e. a full table that's being dragged.

EDIT: based on your comment, to do something where you'd convert cell 1 to an `h1` and cell 2 to a `p`, you'd do:

```
$('selector').draggable({
  helper: function()
  {
    var $ret = $("<div></div>");
    $ret.append( '<h1>' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text() + '</h1>');
    $ret.append( '<p>' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text() + '</p>');
    // ...

    return $ret;
  }

});
```

Comment: That is perfect thanks, I see exactly how to do it. But when I just read the docs it says "A function that will return a DOMElement to use while dragging."

Comment: This means that the dropped element will be the tr

Comment: @JohnMagnolia good question.  It will likely be the original element, as the helper is just for the visual representation of the drag.  On drop you'd likely need to extract the information from the original element that was dropped.  Looking at the `drop` event handler, you have access to the `helper` object as a part of the `ui` object in the event handler.  See  http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop