# Change JQuery UI draggable helper option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, clone, draggable, helper

Can I change helper option? Like that :

```
$(".item").draggable({
    helper : function() {
        if( $(this).data("type") == "store" )
            return "clone";
        else
            return "original";
    }
});
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8502045/829533